# React how to get accessToken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bearer-token

I want to send a post with fetching. But I get 401 error: www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token".
I am using Userfront.accessToken() but It did not work.

How can I get accestoken for bearer authentication?

```
const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form.current);
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT + "user/me/contract", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Userfront.accessToken()}`,
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json());
  };
```

Note:

```
console.log(`Bearer ${Userfront.accessToken()}`);
```

> > Bearer [object Object]

Comment: What is in your `Userfront.accessToken`?

Comment: I added it to my questionç @Mr.spShuvo

Comment: Should return a token type string by calling that function. Can your share the code inside of that function?

Comment: It is a component: import Userfront from "@userfront/react"; @Mr.spShuvo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("fray_access_token")}`,
```

In this application, token gets a different name.
When I look from inspects, I use it and it works!

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify(Userfront.accessToken()) please stringify that object to understand what is going on there then if there is accessToken returning from that function put that string.

I just realized in the doc;

> To handle a request like this -Userfront.accessToken()-, your backend should read the JWT from
> the Authorization header and verify that it is valid using the public
> key found in your Userfront dashboard.

https://userfront.com/guide/auth/

```
fetch('https://api.example.com', {
  method: 'GET'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${Userfront.tokens.accessToken}`
  }
});
```

Comment: It returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I see this from https://userfront.com/guide/auth/

```
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${Userfront.tokens.accessToken}`
  }
```

Comment: console.log(Userfront.tokens.accessToken);  returns null